# Why can't I run git commands after updating to OSX 10.10?

Tags: xcode, macos, git, osx-yosemite

I upgraded from OSX 10.9 to 10.10. When I try to

```
git status
```

I get

```
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
```

1. *Why* do I have to accept a new TOS to run `git`? Is there a workaround to accepting new Xcode TOS?

I know that I could simply [open up Xcode and accept the new user agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197347/agreeing-to-the-xcode-ios-license-requires-admin-privileges-please-re-run-as-r) and carry on. I plan on using Xcode in the future and have no specific objections to using it. Wondering how a developer could, hypothetically, choose to continue running `git` should they disagree with Xcode's new TOS.

Comment: Does `which git` show you `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find that `which git` returns `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` then you are dependent on xcode functionality and its associated TOS.

If you install through another mechanism, `brew` or via [GitHub command line tools](https://github.com/blog/1510-installing-git-from-github-for-mac), you would not receive this prompt. You may want to make sure your other version is earlier in your path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: For me, `which git` provides `/usr/bin/git`.  What do you mean by "earlier in your path"?

Comment: Meaning that `git` is loaded from locations in your directory path shown by `echo $PATH`. You can always prepend this directory earlier with `PATH=~/usr/bin:$PATH`. If that works at preventing the TOS, then you can add it to your `~/.bashrc` to ensure it's used after reboot.