# The compiler g++ can't create a.out file?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, compiler-errors, c++14

So, I was doing the homework for my C++ class. I was compiling for quite awhile with this statement `g++-5.2.0 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic <file_name>`  in terminal when, for some reason unbeknownst to me, I received this message: `Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.`.

Naively, I ran the command `sudo g++-5.2.0 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic hw2pr3.cpp`, entered in my password, and agreed to the terms.

Now, when I try to compile with `g++-5.2.0 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic hw2pr3.cpp`, I get this statement:

`ld: can't write output file: a.out for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Does anybody know what to do about this?

What's different about the file that I am trying to run now (hw2pr3.cpp) than the files previously is this line:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << "You should give away about $" << donate << ", save about $" << save <<", and live on about $" << live << ".\n";
```

My guess is that either the std::set precision(2) messed it up (this is my first time to use this statement and I don't know if I did it right), or that the '$' in the cout is causing issues.

No, I cannot provide the full source code for this; this is my homework and I will not post it on here.

Comment: If you want help you may have to strip out the parts that would be identifiable as the assignment and provide a generic example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you compile anything at all?  Can you compile and run Hello World?  This seems more like something wrong with the compiler environment, rather than your code.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I can compile and run hello world.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you very much! That fixed it. Do you happen to know why Xcode would have sent that statement?

Comment: Googling the message is a good start and turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197347/agreeing-to-the-xcode-ios-license-requires-admin-privileges-please-re-run-as-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compiled your code with `sudo g++-5.2.0`, you ran the compiler as root, so the output file `a.out` was created as root.  Without `sudo`, you are running as an ordinary user, and again trying to write the output to `a.out`.  But as an ordinary user, you don't have permission to delete / overwrite the root-owned file `a.out`.

So just `sudo rm a.out` and all should be well.