# Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo cannot run git after OS update

Tags: java, xcode, intellij-idea

The IDE is giving an error message that it

`can't start git: /usr/bin/git`, however the path is correct, and it was working before. idea.log contains the following error:

```
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
```

Comment: I've had the same error using Homebrew when downloading packages - I've added the `homebrew` tag.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This generally occurs after the mac OS update. All you need to do in terminal is run

`sudo xcodebuild -license`

and then agree to the terms.