# Appcelerator - Xcode EULA has not been accepted. Launch Xcode and accept the license

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am running appcelerator 4.5.0 and xcode 7.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Running an iOS app gives me:

```
[ERROR] :  Xcode EULA has not been accepted.
[ERROR] :  Launch Xcode and accept the license.
```

I ran `sudo xcodebuild -license` per: ["Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo." when using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197347/agreeing-to-the-xcode-ios-license-requires-admin-privileges-please-re-run-as-r/26197363)

But the error persists.

I then (per: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Uninstalling+Studio) uninstalled appcelerator by deleting:

```
/Applications/Aptana Studio 3
/Applications/Titanium Studio
/Application/Appcelerator Studio
```

and then (per https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/474/how-do-you-uninstall-titanium-and-appcelerator-studio-completely-and-start-from-scratch):

```
rm -rf ~/.appcelerator
rm -rf ~/.titanium
sudo npm uninstall -g titanium
sudo npm uninstall -g alloy
sudo npm uninstall -g acs
sudo npm uninstall -g appcelerator
```

and uninstalled xcode with `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` per: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/

and I deleted Xcode.app from my Applications folder.

After all that I redownloaded xcode via software update, ran `sudo xcodebuild -license` (typing accept at the end), then installed from the site `Appcelerator_Studio.dmg` and ran `appc setup`

But still the error persists.

Any ideas on how to fix?

MORE INFO: After reading https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/155502/using-the-titanium-cli-and-getting-error-you-have-not-agreed-to-the-xcode-license-agreements-please-run-xcodebuild--license I believe I have the same issue (still no resolution though).

Running:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator` is successful but if I run:

`appc titanium build -p ios -T simulator -Y iphone` I get the same errors as above.

UPDATE based on @andre-m comment (referencing https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175069/how-to-accept-xcode-license):

I already mentioned that I have run `sudo xcodebuild -license` but I also tried:

`sudo xcodebuild -license accept` which gives no output and then I still give the error on the build;

`sudo xcode-select -r` no output, error;

`sudo xcode-select --install` outputs: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates` but still errors;

`sudo softwareupdate -l` outputs:`No new software available.` and then still gives the error;

`sudo xcrun cc` outputs `clang: error: no input files`

UPDATE based on @fokke-appcelerator comment (note these results are the same on both a working and non-working machine):

`xcodebuild -checkFirstLaunchStatus; echo $?;` gives `0`

`sudo xcodebuild -checkFirstLaunchStatus; echo $?;` gives `69`

Deleted Xcode.app from Applications (again), reinstalled xcode 7.2.1 -> this time from xcode dmg file [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file) (previously via Software Update), opened Xcode and was not given any EULA dialog.

SOLUTION:

Following @fokke-appcelerator's second I logged the exit code, out, and err of https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js#L333 (which is located here: `/Users/<my_user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib`) and got: `xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-checkFirstLaunchStatus'` because that xcode.js script found an older version of Xcode (4.2.6) that was not removed by `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` as it should have.

Removing the old version of Xcode and reinstalling the current version of Xcode and then reinstalling the simulators (Launch Xcode; Select Xcode > Preferences; Select the Downloads icon; Click the Install button next to the desired simulator), and reinstalling Appcelerator ...the problem is now solved.

Comment: Does this post help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175069/how-to-accept-xcode-license

Comment: Thanks, I did see that post and I have tried all the suggestions without any success. I have updated my post with those results.

Comment: Maybe remove XCode and install it again?

Comment: I guess that was also somewhat unclear. I mentioned I did remove Xcode using `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` but I also deleted the app from Applications (post updated). So yes, I have tried that and it is still giving me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We check if the EULA has been accepted here:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js#L332

Which runs:

```
xcodebuild -checkFirstLaunchStatus
```

And then checks the exit code.

Could you run the above command yourself and then `echo $?` to get the exit code? That should echo `1`. If that is true, then unfortunately it seems like your Xcode installation has a problem.

Maybe reinstall Xcode and instead of using the terminal to accept the license, just open Xcode.

Comment: I'm trying that now (xcode download will take a while), but as a sidenote: `xcodebuild -checkFirstLaunchStatus; echo $?;` on both my machines gives `0` and `sudo xcodebuild -checkFirstLaunchStatus; echo $?;` gives `69` so I'm not sure why one machine is running apps without issue and the other does not.

Comment: So, I deleted and reinstalled Xcode and did not get a EULA when I opened the app.

Comment: When you do a build I assume you're not using sudo right? Could you edit https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js#L333 in the SDK that you use and log the exit code, out and err?

Comment: code: `64`, out: <blank>, and err: `xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-checkFirstLaunchStatus'` which I thought was odd and so I logged the version of xcode and it was `4.2.6` so after looking at xcode.js I found `function findXcodes(next)` and eventually found `/Users/<my_user>/Applications/Xcode.app` and yelled some obscenities. I don't know how that got there or why it wasn't removed when I did `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` but removing it solved the problem. Thanks @fokke-appcelerator now onto posting my Citrix question (hopefully you can help with that one too!)

Comment: Xcode 4.2.6!? Wow, the last Titanium version that [supported](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode) that was 1.8 ;) So that old Xcode version lingering around did it, wow. Glad you've found it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as FYI. I Had same issue and it was because I had downloaded a beta version of xCode but had not opened it (still had current version installed too). Once I opened the beta and went through everything I was able to go back to appc and package app without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you specifically say it, but like the message says, you did launch XCode since install/update and accept the EULA there, yes?

Comment: Good point. I did open xcode but it didn't give me any request to do that. There is a link to the license agreement in `Xcode > About Xcode` but no place to accept it. I also copied the project from my other machine and was able to run it in this xcode without issue.